# Dye Sub printer with specific prints remaining - can I command-line query this?

Tags: command-line, printer, printing

I've got a Sony Dye-Sub printer that holds ink/paper sets - i.e. a very certain amount of ink and paper for ~200 prints.

This information is available to me from within Control Panel > Printers > Preferences > Printer Device Information (i.e. current 189 remaining prints).

Any way I can perhaps get this information from the command line? I'd like to write a little program to tell me when the number of prints gets low (i.e. < 20), rather than suffer the annoying Windows "run out of paper" popup.

I've found the Windows VBScript print utilities, but can't seem to find the request I need for this.

Any suggestions?

Jason

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this too.  It must be something specific to the Sony printer drivers, since most printers (inkjets, etc) will not have a count of pages remaining.

Probably the best bet is to query the printer for information, and print out the list of values it returns and look for the number somewhere.  I doubt there's going to be good documentation on this one.